# How can I improve a messaging system that utilizes the singleton pattern?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I'm working on a piece of software that is constructed from a series of "modules". Modules can be connected together to form the full application (one module might go to another, sort of an implied state machine). Each module can render to the screen, get updates and access state from other modules. Note that the modules are still within the same process, so no IPC needs to be designed into this.

However, these modules do not directly depend on each other. There is a singleton object that has the sole purpose of managing message passing between the modules. When you want to register for an event from any module:

```
CPostMaster::Instance().RegisterEvent("TheEventName", [](std::string const& data) { /* the callback */ });
```

The `data` variable is serialized data. Can be anything, but usually is XML or JSON. To send the event you do:

```
std::string serialized_data = /* serialized data, do this before calling */;
CPostMaster::Instance().SendEvent("TheEventName", serialized_data);
```

The 2nd parameter is optional.

Having a "master authority" for message passing has a drawback: The events themselves can't send varying parameters without utilizing some sort of serialization or type erasure (removes type safety from the picture and impacts performance).

But it also has the benefit of strict/strong coupling not being required, which means that at any given time a different module can be responsible for sending a specific event without the receiving modules having to change.

The alternative seems to be not using a singleton, and instead each module receives an object that it can use to subscribe to. This could get messy especially when you are passing them around everywhere, it will quickly mean that functions start taking boilerplate parameters.

What is a good design for message passing in a system such as this? How can it be improved and be made manageable? Type safety and open/close principles are important here. I think it's OK to have direct dependencies across modules so long as they can be mocked (for unit testing) and easily swapped out should modules change without severely impacting the whole system (but this is part of the open/close principle).

Comment: Even not used in IPC, it is an IPC design - make it peer to peer

Comment: Serializing is kind-of silly here. Take a look at Boost.Any as a replacement, which is type-safe but avoids the overhead of serializing/deserializing. Also, this looks like a good place for a signal/slot mechanism, so check out Boost.Signal. Lastly, if registering returned a typed function `function<void (int)> f = hub.register<void (int)>();`, that would be the time when the type is checked and invocations later are both fast and type-safe.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I don't see how that would work. PostMaster would most likely need to keep track of subscribers like so: `std::map<std::string, boost::signals2::signal<void (int)>>` where we have a collection of signals mapped to the specific event name. But each event might require a different signature (maybe 2 ints instead of 1).

Comment: The PostMaster would indeed have to type-erase the stored callbacks, using e.g. Boost.Any. Another important thing is that I wouldn't necessarily mix retrieving callbacks with actually calling them. Assuming that retrieving callbacks would be done rarely, the performance of these operations then doesn't matter that much. In the best case, actually calling is then not much more expensive than a function call.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the singleton or of the serialization? Those are 2 separate questions.

Comment: You ask for a design without stating the requirements. That makes this question unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I dislike singletons. The only singleton I accept is a singleton manager (some sort of central instance distributor) that handles a defined init and deinit of all "singletons" in a defined order.

But back to your problem:
Your title already has the solution: Define a message interface. If you want type-safety define an `IMessage` with common attributes.
Then define specializations of `IMessage` which then are consumed by your callbacks.

The tricky part is: You will need RTTI for that, which is odd in c++, I know but might be worth the benefits, if you are restricted to gcc or visual studio, you could make use of those types, or implement some simple RTTI in the `IMessage` itself to avoid `dynamic_cast`.

To avoid boilerplate code in a callback which checks and casts around the `IMessage` I would provide a utility function (pseudo code, adjust for pointers, references, smart ptrs, const correctness etc.)

```
T SafeCast<T>(IMessage message);
```

depending on the implementation of your compiler you should add restrictions to `T` to be of a sub type of `IMessage` and what should happen when the cast fails (exception, `nullptr`, etc).

Alternatively: Check how others have solved this (maybe Qt's Signals&Slots or something in Boost)

Comment: That's a packaging format for the message, but how would you handle the observer pattern here without a singleton as it is currently implemented? Those `IMessage` objects have to be delivered somehow right? Or by your standards is the singleton pattern appropriate here for inter-module communication?

Comment: @void.pointer I would expose a singleton manager from which you get an interface implementation of your observer pattern. So the only dependency would be the interface and not a specific implementation. The observer pattern you described is IMHO already best suited for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the sub modules dependent on a parent class (in your case the singleton). Then you could pass this object's reference along the line, to be used in the modules.

```
  Module(Handler& h) : _h(h) { }
  void do_stuff(){
   _h.RegisterEvent("TheEventName", [](std::string const& data)
   { /* the callback */ })
```

Then I would register your Module class itself, or another class, as an Event, and on the Handler side, I would formalize the messaging in a way that you'd get multiple callbacks instead of just one. You'd have to formalize your message though, but you'd have type safety instead of passing strings. 
For example the handler, while parsing a message, he'd call:

```
   _callback.start(); //signals the start of a message
   _callback.signalParam1(1); //calls Module.signalParam(int); 
   _callback.signalParam2("test"); //calls Module.signalParam2(const char*);
   _callback.end();
```

Your Module would need to implement those.